# Веб-Скрапинг на питоне

Tags: python

Добрый день дорогие форумчане. В универе нам задали создать проект на питоне для итоговой аттестации в семестре.
И так, нам нужно создать такую вещь как веб скрапинг - получить список ссылок на клипы ютюб по ключевому слову 25 ссылок
Знающих людей прошу помочь и объяснить под что нужно копать что бы создать этот самый "Веб-Скрапинг"?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Попробуйте капнуть с сторону youtube_dl

Comment: Посмотрите на библиотеку `bs4`

Comment: я ознакомился с библиотеками requests и bs4, но парсинг происходит криво ( теги HTML идут так, как будто их вообще через bs4 не прогоняли).